# Yii2 invalid backtick in query

Tags: yii2

If I run this,

```
->addSelect(new Expression('IFNULL(SUM(supply), 0) AS sum_supply'))
```

it generate

```
IFNULL(SUM(supply), `0` AS `sum_supply` FROM ...
```

which is invalid query, with backtick around 0.

How can I remove that backtick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick fix :

```
->addSelect([new Expression('IFNULL(SUM(supply), 0) AS sum_supply')])
```

or

```
->addSelect(['IFNULL(SUM(supply), 0) AS sum_supply'])
```

Array must be used in this case because `addSelect()` split input string by comma